# Does Autofac support register services in Blazor WebAssembly Lazy load assemblies

Tags: autofac, blazor-webassembly

Blazor WebAssembly support [lazy loading assemblies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/webassembly-lazy-load-assemblies?view=aspnetcore-5.0) - the assemblies are not available at start up. Autofac used to support updateing container with builder.Update(container), but it seems to be obsolete since v5.0. Is there a workaround to register services after the assemblies being lazy loaded?

Answer (score 1):

While there is [an issue to add some docs here](https://github.com/autofac/Documentation/issues/97), the long and short of it is that there is no formal guidance for supporting container immutability like this. In general, updating the container mid-app isn't actually a very good idea anyway, which is why it was made immutable.

[Here is the discussion chain with a looooot of options](https://github.com/autofac/Autofac/issues/811) that you can use for inspiration, but for the most part it boils down to:

- Use lambdas as registrations rather than reflection - this defers the resolution of the type until it needs it.
- Consider things like `RegistrationSource` implementations (and, yeah, there's very little doc here, but look through the issue I linked for some pointers).
- Think about things like child lifetime scope registrations to add things dynamically rather than registering right in the root container. You can dispose and re-create a scope; you can't do that so much with a container.

Unfortunately, though, there's really not support at large for something like this. I'd recommend if you're using lazy loaded assemblies to figure out a way to make sure the stuff you're lazy loading isn't something that needs to be registered at the root.

Likely there will not be any new support for this in the future. As .NET Core heads toward the ability to do linker trimming of unnecessary types and ship single-binary executables, it's more and more clear that the majority use case is *not* in lazy loading assemblies.

Comment: Lambdas registration won't help in this case. It also cause 'could not load file or assembly' error as the DLL is not loaded yet. I couldn't find RegistrationSource in the document.

Comment: Thanks Travis. Linker trimming and single-binary executables are not conflicting with lazy loading. With a modular architecture, there are services in plug-ins/modules that only be loaded in certain circumstance. I hope Autofac can provide possibility for developer to implement incremental registration – register the servers in a module when loading it.

Comment: As noted, we won't be allowing mutable containers. The issue I linked explains why. Linker trimming does conflict with lazy loading when it comes to DI: If the linker trims constructors it doesn't use but that are required for reflective DI, you won't get DI. Lazy loading doesn't allow for correct trimming. But that's neither here nor there; check the issue thread for ideas and workarounds.